# remove elements from list of SpatialLinesDataFrames based values in a numeric vector

Tags: r, list, loops, r-sp

I have a list of SpatialLinesDataFrame objects and I want to remove list items that have a value contained data.frame column equal to one of the values in a simple numeric vector. I want to iterate this process as the actual list is massive. Here is simplified example data with a loop that is not doing what I want it to do:

```
#create list of single-feature SpatialLineDataFrame
library(raster)

l1 <- cbind(c(0,3), c(0,3))
l2 <- cbind(c(0, 13), c(0, 1))
l3 <- cbind(c(0, 24), c(0,22.5))
l4 <- cbind(c(0, 1), c(0,13))
l5 <- cbind(c(0, 6), c(0,6))
Sldf <- spLines(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5, attr=data.frame(lineID=1:5))
linel <- lapply(1:5, function(i) Sldf[i,])
#numeric vector
x <- c(1,3,5)

newlist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(linel)){
  if (linel[[i]]@data$lineID == x) {
    newlist[[i]] <- linel[[i]]
  }
}
```

I get the following error msg:

> Warning message:
>       1: In if (linel[[i]]@data$lineID == x) { :
>         the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

But what I want is to remove the list elements with lineID == 1 or 3 or 5 (only coincidentally same as index # in the example) from the list, and end up with:

```
newlist

[[1]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : lineID 
value       :      2 

[[2]]
class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
features    : 1 
extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : lineID 
value       :      4
```

Comment: sorry - raster package added to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sapply` from base R and extract the `lineID` from each `linel` and then keep only the ones which are not present in `x`.

```
linel[!sapply(linel, function(data) data$lineID) %in% x]


#[[1]]
#class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 0, 13, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA 
#variables   : 1
#names       : lineID 
#value       :      2 

#[[2]]
#class       : SpatialLinesDataFrame 
#features    : 1 
#extent      : 0, 1, 0, 13  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : NA 
#variables   : 1
#names       : lineID 
#value       :      4
```

---

Some more methods using `purrr`

```
purrr::discard(linel, ~ .$lineID %in% x)
purr::keep(linel, ~ ! .$lineID %in% x)
```

---

As far as your `for` loop is concerned you are checking the value with `==`. As `x` is a vector of values and not a single value using `==` gives you the warning that it is using only the first value from `x`.  Instead you want to do it with `%in%` as there are multiple values in `x`. However, using `%in%` would return a vector of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values which you have to wrap in `any` then. Moreover even after all those changes what the code is doing is saving those list elements with `lineID` in `x` in `newlist` and not deleting it from `linel`. So what you might need is

```
newlist <- list()
j <- 1
for (i in 1:length(linel)){
   if (!any(linel[[i]]$lineID %in% x)) {
       newlist[[j]] <- linel[[i]]
       j = j + 1
    }
}
```

and now `newlist` is the list that you want.

Comment: you are a genius and have made my day.